# How to trigger a "UNIQUE" contraint on a column depending on the data value in PostgreSQL 12?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, unique-constraint

I have a table called "node" and a column called "title" which currently contains multiple duplicate values.

My need is that for a specific value pattern : 'IA-%', trigger a UNIQUE contraint so that I can't have for example two rows with this value 'IA-1234'

I don't want the whole column to be UNIQUE since there are other values that I don't need to be unique in this column, my need is only for this specific pattern (or multiple identified pattern).

Is it even possible, and if so, how to proceed ?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like this is perfectly possible. Can you add a few rows of sample data, and a couple of cases that should succeed and fail?

Comment: `IA-%` isn't a regex. It's a `LIKE` pattern that matches *every* character after the dash, including letters. What do you actually want?

Answer (score 2):

UNIQUE constraints are implemented using unique indexes.

It's possible to create [partial indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/indexes-partial.html) that only apply to a subset of a table defined by a WHERE expression. In fact, partial unique indexes is one of the examples in the documentation, example 11-3:

```
CREATE TABLE tests (
    subject text,
    target text,
    success boolean,
    ...
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tests_success_constraint ON tests (subject, target)
    WHERE success;
```

The question's pattern is a LIKE pattern that matches every string that starts with `IA-` so the equivalent partial index would be :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tests_partial_constraint ON tests (field1)
    WHERE field1 LIKE 'IA-%';
```

Comment: Congrats on reaching 100K rep! Always really appreciated the answers and discussions you have - a real value to the community!